# Issue with classes "control"

Tags: class, object, destructor

so here's the thing.. I have one object that is responsable to create another different object, this created object can be destroyed or not (that depends on the user). The trick part is that the "creator" object is called again and if the other object wasnt destoyed, this class cant create this object again, but if the other object was destoyed, this class need to create again and the loop goes on.

i tried 2 solutions: 
Global varible as "flag", it worked fine, but i got roasted for use global variable;
second was to make the destructor return a value to this flag, but i cant return from destructor.

Does yall know another way other than global variable?

Really appretiate the attention, cheers.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a programming language, so I'm going to assume Perl (with [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) as the OO toolkit).

Here's a possible implementation of what you're describing:

```perl
use v5.14.0;
use warnings;

package Item {
    use Moo;

    has _owner => (
        is       => 'ro',
        weak_ref => 1,
        clearer  => 1,
    );

    sub detach {
        my ($self) = @_;
        if (my $owner = $self->_owner) {
            $self->_clear_owner;
            $owner->_clear_item;
        }
    }

    sub BUILD {
        my ($self) = @_;
        say "!! constructing $self";
    }

    sub DEMOLISH {
        my ($self) = @_;
        say "!! destroying $self";
    }
}

package Owner {
    use Moo;

    has item => (
        is      => 'lazy',
        clearer => '_clear_item',
    );
    sub _build_item {
        my ($self) = @_;
        return Item->new(_owner => $self);
    }
}

my $owner = Owner->new;
say "owner = $owner";
say "(1) owner->item = ", $owner->item;
say "(2) owner->item = ", $owner->item;
say "entering block {";
{
    my $item = $owner->item;
    say "  (3) owner->item = $item";
    $item->detach;
    say "  detached item = $item";
}
say "} leaving block";
say "(4) owner->item = ", $owner->item;
say "owner is still = $owner";
```

When I run this code, it produces the following output:

```
owner = Owner=HASH(0x23e52f8)
!! constructing Item=HASH(0x23e4950)
(1) owner->item = Item=HASH(0x23e4950)
(2) owner->item = Item=HASH(0x23e4950)
entering block {
  (3) owner->item = Item=HASH(0x23e4950)
  detached item = Item=HASH(0x23e4950)
!! destroying Item=HASH(0x23e4950)
} leaving block
!! constructing Item=HASH(0x23eb328)
(4) owner->item = Item=HASH(0x23eb328)
owner is still = Owner=HASH(0x23e52f8)
!! destroying Item=HASH(0x23eb328)
```

The idea is that the `Owner` class has an `item` attribute (which stores an instance of the `Item` class). This attribute is lazy, so it is only constructed on demand (the first time you use it).

As you can see by looking at the `owner->item` lines 1, 2, and 3, no new objects are constructed: `$owner` remembers its `item`.

However, it is possible to destroy `item` explicitly by calling `$owner->item->detach`. This is possible because each instance of `Item` has an (optional) `_owner` attribute; i.e. each item remembers its owner. This is a weak reference because otherwise we'd have a reference cycle (owner keeps item alive, item keeps owner alive).

When we call `$item->detach`, `$item` automatically removes itself from its owner (if it still has one). It is then automatically destroyed as soon as any other reference to it is gone (in the example, this happens when the local variable `$item` ceases to exist at the end of its block).

`$owner`, having been reset to its initial state, then automatically re-creates a new `item` the next time it is needed.

Comment: it is c++, but i did undestand the logic.. i couldnt think in anything else
Gonna try to adapt this code to c++. Thanks bro, i really appreciate